# Which amazon web service instance must I use for standalone?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ns-3

I am running an ns3 network simulator experiment (https://www.nsnam.org/) on c4.4xlarge compute-optimized instance.

My goal is just to borrow a good ubuntu computer to run simulation which takes a long time to run (~ 2days). It is standalone and doesn't have to be a server.

However I noticed with only one instance it is quite slow. What should I do to make the most of the service in this case?

Comment: when you look at CPU usage, are all cores fully used?

Comment: I am using c4.4x Large which is supposed to have many cores. However I cannot find where to check how many cores are being used. Under the monitor tab, cpu utilization graph shows constant 6 % usage. However the task is running very slow. The task is a unix script with many calls to ns3 simulations

Comment: try to login via `ssh` and use `top`

Comment: The overall cpu usage shown is 6 %. But the task (owifi ) shows ~100 pc cpu usage
   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                 
  2132 root      20   0  285244  58488  38248 R  99.8  0.2  12:27.48 owifi

Comment: It seems that your program is running only on one core instead of all 16.

Comment: I think so too. How do I make it use all 16. My scripts have a lot of independent calls to ns3. Do I have to write low level parallel programming code or is there a simpler work-around

Comment: Without seeing your script that's impossible to tell. ns3 supports multi-threading in general, so it should work, but you still need to adapt your script.

Comment: The script is sequential commands that calls ns3 independently. I split it into 36 separate scripts and ran each thro ssh in 36 separate tabs from my local comp. Now the cpu percentage shows 100%. Seems like now it uses all 16 cores. whoa. ill see if the task gets done soon.Thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 0):

If the job you wish to run is too slow, then you have three choices:

- Have patience, or
- Use a more powerful EC2 instance, or
- Use more EC2 instances

If the simulator is able to run across multiple VMs in parallel, take a look at **Amazon EC2 Spot Instances**. They are low-priced instances that are made available when there is spare capacity on EC2. They can be as little as 90% of the standard price. The downside is that a rise in the Spot Price could cause the instances to be terminated with only two minutes notice.

Comment: The task is running slower than I expect of c4.4xlarge instance. The cpu usage surprisingly shows only 6 %: There is just a script running at a slow pace. The script is a sequence of calls to ns3 simulations.

Comment: How about dedicated host. Will it solve the problem. I tried getting it but was stuck when it said I have to make a request for increasing limits on number of dedicated host from 0 to more. So I made the request and am now waiting for response.

Comment: If I do get multiple instances, will I have to split up the script, and run one on each instance? And will I have to install ns3 software separately on each instance?

Comment: Is there a way to have auto scale kinda thing, where a batch processing jobs is automatically assigned to multiple instances parallelly if i get some instances running

Comment: Auto Scaling is merely a way of running systems in parallel. You will be responsible for figuring out how to run your application in parallel (eg pulling from a queue). A Dedicated Host only affects pricing not performance. Since your CPU is low, something else must be causing the slowness (eg insufficient memory, or a slow disk). You will need to use standard Systems Administration techniques to figure out why it is running slow (it is not related to AWS itself) -- monitor memory and take a look at the `Queue Length` on your EBS volumes.

Comment: I fixed the low cpu usage thing by diving the job into several smaller ones such that each cpu core is used. However I am puzzled by your statement that dedicated host is only about pricing. I see that dedicated host is almost always expensively priced. Then what is the use of it if not better performance over shared hardware.

Comment: As I said, "A Dedicated Host only affects pricing". An instance running on a Dedicated Host is exactly the same as an instance running in Shared Tenancy. The difference is that the whole Host is assigned to an Account and that Account can decide which instances to run on that Host. This is in contrast to normal "Shared Tenancy" where an instance for Account A could run on the same host as an instance for Account B. It comes down to security requirements and software licensing requirements (eg some licenses are based on underlying CPUs of the host).

Comment: I understand that the two instances are same. But in dedicated mode, I can run several instances on the hardware exclusively and thus get better performance. If I have a dedicated host doesn't it means only i can run instances on it. In shared mode other instances not related to my task can be run on the hardware machine. Therefore in dedicated host, i can use the whole resources of the machine for my instances. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: Amazon EC2 instances receive resources (virtual CPUs, RAM and locally-attached disk) based upon the Instance Type chosen. AWS does not over-commit. Therefore, instances will always receive their allocated resources regardless of any other users on the "Host" computer. Instances will *never* be affected by noisy neighbours other instances on the same Host. A Dedicated Host offers no performance improvements.

Comment: I see. I didn't know that. So the additional charge of dedicated host is only for security and license requirement.  Thanks a lot for the info!